# Heatmap in Jupyter using Plotly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

How would I convert this code to work 'offline' in the Jupyter notebook?

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace = go.Heatmap(z=[[1, 20, 30],
                      [20, 1, 60],
                      [30, 60, 1]])
data=[trace]
py.iplot(data, filename='basic-heatmap')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
```

and plot via

```
plotly.offline.iplot(data, filename='basic-heatmap')
```